# angularjs translate placeholder

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am using angular translator for translating my html buttons and labels, problem is when i used inside placeholder i am getting junk characters for french language. But same is working well in span tag. what would be the problem with placeholder.

```
  <input data-ng-model="vm.search" class="form-control"  type="search"
                           ng-attr-placeholder="{{'resources.contacts-organisations-searchplaceholder' | translate }}...">
```

[image]

same stuff is working with span

```
 <span translate="resources.contacts-organisations-searchplaceholder"></span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sorry little late:
But i created a directive for this that will solve your problem.

```
    app.directive('ngBindPlaceholder', ['$sce', '$parse', '$compile', function($sce, $parse, $compile){
   return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function ngBindHtmlCompile(tElement, tAttrs) {
      var ngBindHtmlGetter = $parse(tAttrs.ngBindPlaceholder);
      var ngBindPlaceholderWatch = $parse(tAttrs.ngBindPlaceholder, function getStringValue(value) {
        return (value || '').toString();
      });
      $compile.$$addBindingClass(tElement);

      return function ngBindHtmlLink(scope, element, attr) {
        $compile.$$addBindingInfo(element, attr.ngBindPlaceholder);

        scope.$watch(ngBindPlaceholderWatch, function ngBindWatchAction() {
          // we re-evaluate the expr because we want a TrustedValueHolderType
          // for $sce, not a string
          element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngBindHtmlGetter(scope)) || '');
          var plc = element.text();
          element.attr('placeholder',plc);
        });
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

Uses in HTML:

```
<input type="text" id = "name" data-ng-bind-placeholder="'Label.name' | translate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are You sure that syntax is correct? Seems `{{'resources.contacts-organisations-searchplaceholder' | translate }}` will pass string `resources.contacts-organisations-searchplaceholder` not a string at this object's property

Comment: No, i placed it right. I added the screen shot, please have a look

Comment: i resolved the issue, i have modified the below code 

  $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(null);

previously it was like 

$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');